# Informatica - Trigger next workflow upon completion of the first workflow

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am working on Informatica to automatically run the Workflow B upon the completion of the Workflow A. I did research on how to do this and the best that I encountered is using PMCMD but I cannot find the PMCMD.exe file in the installation folder of my Informatica power center. I am using version 8.1.1. I don't know if the PMCMD is available in this version. Kindly advise for alternative solutions. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with **pmcmd** utility, but there's another option. You can use an `Event Wait` task in Workflow B, right after the `Start` task and make it wait for a flat file, e.g. `workflowA.done`. And add a `Command Task` as the last one in your WorkflowA to perform a `touch workflowA.done` command. Use the appropriate path for your case (might be `$PMTargetFileDir` for example).

Start both your workflows at the same time, Workflow B will process the tasks after the control file gets created.

Answer (score 0):

`pmcmd.exe` is available in the Informatica installation folder for Informatica **server**.

Comment: our client uses informatica power center only, Can you suggest other options to make this work? thank you

Answer (score 0):

For my system it was in the below path:

/infa/server/bin

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is controlled by an external independant scheduler